# ARM template error on storage Queue Service as Optional Parameter

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-storage-queues

[image: MainTemplate]

I was trying to deploy queue service as optional parameter with default blank value, template first create storage account then queue service as nested resource. template throwing error Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource '[concat(parameters('storageName'),'/default/',parameters('storagequeues')[copyIndex()])]'
at line '91' and column '9' is not valid: The language expression property array index '0' is out of bounds.

for some reason schema validating nested resource name before condition evaluation. Is this expected behavior ? if not please suggest work around.

I have tried with condition  "condition": "[not(contains(parameters('storagequeues'),'none'))]", and Having defaultvalue="none" then it won\t create queue. it works fine but this is not desired way of doing.

Answer (score 1):

This template creating a queue under a storage account may meet you need.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the name of the Azure Storage account."
      }
    },
    "queueName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the name of the blob container."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the location in which the Azure Storage resources should be deployed."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "properties": {
        "accessTier": "Hot"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "queueServices/queues",
          "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
          "name": "[parameters('queueName')]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have seen this `'The language expression property array index '0' is out of bounds.'` error before, but the reason may different. I cannot see your `defaultValue` in `'storagequeue'`, maybe the null array cause this issue. You can refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1931df0c-b406-45a0-b48d-232c50570d02/invalid-template-unable-to-process-template-language-expressions-for-resource-creating-multiple-vm).

Comment: @Bala Murali, please let me know if my answer helps you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes error is because default value for queue name is null, But main reason i posted question is , i have condition in resource [greater(length(param(name)>0))] , so i expect condition should evaluate first  before [copyindex] in resource name validates. I want to storage queue to be optional param  in ARM creating storage account, with this problem i simply had to split storage queue creation into different template (same as you did in reply ). So it is known limitation of ARM.

Comment: Okay, I get your point now. After testing with `copyIndex()`, I found that 'Copying nested resources is not supported' in ARM template. Since we need our queue depends on Storage Account, we can not use that function. Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources#copy-limits